# how to change text color of options menu and drop down navigation of Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock with a theme whos parent is Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar (generated with http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator ).

the problem is that the text for dropdown navigation list items, dropdown navigation title in actionbar and options menu list items (on devices with menu key) is dark instead of white. I checked it on both 4.2 device and 2.3 emulator.

something weird is that tabs navigation that automatically changes to dropdown menu in landscape mode has the correct text color both in title and list item, but a simple dropdown navigation doesn't..

I tried overriding some colors in the actionbar style but it didn't change anything.

how do I fix this ?

btw - if I change the theme's parent to Theme.Sherlock, those colors are correct, but then the activity background is dark..